# Getting the public signing key from a Worklight Native API

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I want to use Worklight application authenticity in an Android Native Application. I have already configured my customsecuritytest and I have included the libraries that I need into my android project. The problem appears when I need to export the public signing key. I know how to do it in a hybrid application, you just need to right click over the android environment. But what about the native API project? How can I get the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user experience is not great here. At all.
I've created a defect to correct this.

To add the public signing key, you need to use same public signing key as you would for a Hybrid application. This includes following the same steps. Meaning, create a Hybrid application with the Android environment, generate the public signing key and copy it over to the Native API's application-descriptor.xml.

Basically, do over slide #17 from the [Application Authenticity Protection training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/09_15_Application_Authenticity_Protection.pdf).